# When replying, stop adding "undisclosed-recipients:" to "To:" list

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I exchange emails with a third-party which always replies with me in the BCC field.

That is, when I look at their emails, they appear as

[image]

The problem is that when I then click "Reply All", the To: field contains both their email address ***and*** "undisclosed-recipients:".

If I forget to remove the latter and just send the email, I get an immediate "error email" from "System administrator" saying it obviously couldn't send the email to "undisclosed-recipients:".

Is there a way to stop this behavior? It's kind of annoying having to delete that error email every time I forget to delete "undisclosed-recipients:" (which is all the time).

Comment: Why do you 'click reply' all if you only want to reply to one person?

Comment: @Tetsujin, habit. The vast majority of emails I send are within a group, so Reply All is a must. This is an exception, but... well, it's a habit. Regardless, this feels like a really weird behavior.

Comment: Agreed, it's the app being a bit dozy, but the 'quick fix' is *'stop pressing the wrong button'* ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin fair enough!